# expected string or bytes-like object in Django save() method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.2

I have `Job Model` that I can see list of them, create new one and see details of one of them. But when I want to edit objects of this model, I got this error:

> ```
> match = datetime_re.match(value)
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
> ```

And in `Traceback` this line be come bold:

> `job_resume.save()`

This is my files:

```
#Views.py
resume = get_object_or_404(JobRecord, id=id)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AddAdminJobForm(request.POST,  request.FILES,instance=resume)
    if form.is_valid():
        job_resume = form.save(commit=False)
        job_resume.upload_url = form.cleaned_data['upload_url']
        job_resume.time_start = date_picker(date=request.POST['time-start-input'])
        job_resume.time_end = date_picker(date=request.POST['time-end-input'])
        job_resume.save()
        return redirect('administrator:view_admin_job_resume')
else:
    form = AddAdminJobForm(instance=resume)
template = 'administrator/resumes/add_edit_resume.html'
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, template, context)

#forms.py 
class AddAdminJobForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = JobRecord
    fields = '__all__'

#date_picker function:
def date_picker(date):
if date:
    gregorian_date = jdatetime.date.togregorian(jdatetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%d"))
else:
    gregorian_date  = jdatetime.date.togregorian(jdatetime.datetime.now().date())
return gregorian_date
```

**What is wrong with this codes?**

Comment: What is `date_picker` here?

Comment: Can you share your `AddAdminJobForm`? It looks a bit strange to manually add post parameters here.

Comment: OK ,I will add all of them. `date_picker` is the function that change `jalali date` that has been gotten from user to UTC date. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: That should be done in the form.

Comment: I add all of coeds @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Is is possible to explain more? This `error` create because I done this in my view? @DanielRoseman